# I want the text to appear in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the text to fade-in in sequence using jQuery.

This is what I want to do.

```
Head -> 0.5s wait -> Body -> 0.5s wait -> Foot -> 0.5s ->Head1 ->... -> 
body3 -> 0.5s wait -> Foot2
```

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    show($i);
    setTimeout(function() {}, 3000);
    $('.group-a .target' + $i).removeClass('acitve');
  }
});

function show($index) {
  var target;
  setTimeout(function() {
    target = $('.group-a .target' + $index).addClass('active');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.group-a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.group-a .target1>* {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.group-a .target2>* {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.group-a .target3>* {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.group-a .target1 .part-1 {
  transition-delay: 0.5s
}

.group-a .target1 .part-2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.group-a .target1 .part-3 {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

.group-a .target1.active>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.group-a .target2.active>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.group-a .target3.active>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.group-a .target2 .part-1 {
  transition-delay: 0.5s
}

.group-a .target2 .part-2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.group-a .target2 .part-3 {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

.group-a .target3 .part-1 {
  transition-delay: 0.5s
}

.group-a .target3 .part-2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.group-a .target3 .part-3 {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="group-a">
    <div class="target1">
      <div class="part-1">Head</div>
      <div class="part-2">Body</div>
      <div class="part-3">Foot</div>
    </div>

    <div class="target2">
      <div class="part-1">Head1</div>
      <div class="part-2">Body1</div>
      <div class="part-3">Foot1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="target3">
      <div class="part-1">Head2</div>
      <div class="part-2">Body2</div>
      <div class="part-3">Foot2</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please example what you EXPECT it to do and what it actually does that you need help with. I see fading but cannot see in your explanation what it does not do right. This does not make sense `Head -> 0.5s wait -> Body -> 0.5s wait -> Foot -> 0.5s ->Head1 ->... -> body3 ->0.5s wait -> Foot2`

Comment: Also spelling: `removeClass('acitve');`

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I had the same requirement on my previous project so we took help of WOW.JS & animate.css libraries.

Comment: Yes. I want the letters to appear in order. For example, you want the target members of the target 1 to appear in turn, then the target 2 members, and finally the target 3.

Comment: There are typos in your code. In the first use of removeClass() the class name is misspelled. Also, you would not use the $ symbol with your variable names in jQuery. For example, you should replace '$i' with 'i' and so on.

Comment: @mplungjan removeClass() is not jquery method ?

Comment: @Mark oh.Thank you . I'm used php There seems to be confusion.

Comment: @koboso - I expect you meant active and not acitive since your addClass has active

Comment: @mplungjan what is solution? I don't know that..

Comment: I ma just pointing out you need to spell active the same way in both add and removeclass

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for answer

Comment: @koboso I agree that there is some confusion. But you're not using $ as an alias for the jQuery object, nor are you referring to a PHP variable in your JavaScript for loop (i.e. the 'i'). Your code is problematic.

Comment: @Mark  i'm check it my code bundle.! thank you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written too much code in css which is not required. Add a same class to all the target divs to reduce the code and use **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** jQuery to add class in each element and window **[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)** for delay

```js
$(".target").each(function(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.group-a .target').eq(i).addClass('active');
  }, i * 3000);
})
```

```css
.group-a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.group-a .target>* {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.group-a .target .part-1 {
  transition-delay: 0.5s
}

.group-a .target .part-2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.group-a .target .part-3 {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

.group-a .target.active>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-a">
  <div class="target1 target">
    <div class="part-1">Head</div>
    <div class="part-2">Body</div>
    <div class="part-3">Foot</div>
  </div>
  <div class="target2 target">
    <div class="part-1">Head1</div>
    <div class="part-2">Body1</div>
    <div class="part-3">Foot1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="target3 target">
    <div class="part-1">Head2</div>
    <div class="part-2">Body2</div>
    <div class="part-3">Foot2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```